# GitLab CI mysql connect

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to connect to MySQL using their shared runners. I wrote the following code:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://' +  db_username + ":" + db_password + "@" + db_host + ":" + db_port + "/" + db_name + "?host="+ db_host + "?port=" + db_port

db_username = XXX
db_password = XXX
db_host = mysql
db_port = 3306
db_name = XXX
```

And the following .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: python:3.6-stretch

services:
  - mysql:latest

variables:
  FLASK_APP: "program.py"
  MYSQL_DATABASE: XXX
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "XXX"

install_dependencies:
  stage: build
  script:
    - apt update && apt upgrade -y
    - pip install pipenv
    - pipenv install

run_unit_tests:
  stage: test
  script:
    - apt update && apt upgrade -y
    - pip install pipenv
    - pipenv install
    - pipenv run pytest -s
```

When the runner starts I get the following error on the run_unit_tests job:

```
'Can\'t connect to local MySQL server through socket \'/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock\'
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you configured your python app to use the db host `mysql`?

```
Host: mysql
User: root
```

If that does not help, try installing `mysql-client` in your python image first:

```
install_dependencies:
  stage: build
  script:
    - apt update && apt upgrade -y && apt install -y mysql-client
    - pip install pipenv
    - pipenv install
```